# What's the best way to create items programmatically inside a Service?

Tags: android, service

So, I have to create few items, like Buttons and TextViews, from a service.

Since I need to pass along a Context when I create a new one, and since my service doesn't have one, I thought about doing it like this

```
Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
```

It works, but is it the best solution? I read a lot about how you have to be extra careful when using application context, so I'm not sure if it's the proper way to achieve what I need

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need buttons and textviews in a `Service` ?

Comment: I have an Overlay Service which, as you can guess by the name, it puts on screen buttons and views when and how I need them, even when I switch between different applications - it has to be an overlay on top of different applications, so that's why. Can you help me or it was just curiosity? :)

Comment: here is how you can acheive it - http://icetea09.com/blog/2015/03/16/android-floating-view-like-facebook-chatheads/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used `Service` instances for that so, this is new for me. However, I stumbled upon [this question about overlay service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top) which gives quite cool solutions. As per your question I guess the following should work within the scope of your `Service` and is safer:

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);
```

Comment: Thanks, I already managed to achieve that overlay, and my solution is pretty similar :) I didn't realize I could have just used _this_ , that's why I was searching for other solutions! Thanks a lot, I'll see if it's stable this way